# How to remove document from all collections in Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have **Mongo database** with 16 collections. All collection has the common field `domain_id`.
How can I remove documents with specified `domain_id` from all collections.

I know only how to remove document from single collection.

```
db.getCollection('collectionName1').remove({domain_id : '123'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method **[`db.getCollectionNames()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db.getCollectionNames)** to get a list of all the collections in your database, iterate the list using the JavaScript's **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**
method to remove the document from each collection:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (col) {
    db.getCollection(col).remove({domain_id : '123'})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Mondo doesn't allow for linking collections. So, you do have to do it for each separate collection.